# I get the error uncaught exception: TypeError: doc.addresses.append is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a structure like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("3c4b1475238d3b4dd5000001"),
username: "kris",
addresses: 
[
      {
        name: "home",
        street: "123 Some Ave",
        city: "Cul City",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 12345
      },

      {
        name: "work",
        street: "1234 Sea Blvd",
        city: "Cul City",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 54321
      }
]
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
UID=ObjectId("3c4b1475238d3b4dd5000001")
doc=db.users.findOne({_id: UID})
new_address={name:'work', street:'17w. 18th St', city: 'New York', state:'NY', zip:10011}
doc['addresses'].append(new_address)
```

But i get this error:
**uncaught exception: TypeError: doc.addresses.append is not a function :**
How can i solve it?

Comment: Does `doc['addresses'].push(new_address)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper `javascript` method to append to an array is `push`.

So, instead of:

```js
doc['addresses'].append(new_address)
```

use:

```js
doc['addresses'].push(new_address)
```